# How to remove Autodesk Access "rootkit"?

Tags: uninstall, rootkit

I installed some (paid) Autodesk products at a point (institutional access, got the license for free) and installed all the software products that come with that including Autodesk Access. When I realized I would be much better off using open source software for my purposes, I tried to uninstall all Autodesk software. Afer I failed, I followed the [11 (!) steps](https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Clean-uninstall.html) described on the Autodesk website.

I believed I succeeded (the program was not listed anymore among the installed apps), but not only is Autodesk Access still on my computer, but it starts itself on boot up of Windows.

Comment: You can use AutoRuns and remove the registry entry causing the application to automatically start.

Comment: @Ramhound I repeatedly removed autostart entries. It adds itself back.

Answer (score -1):

The only way to be sure would be to reinstall Windows. But, surprisingly, after repeatedly doing items from the [list](https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/Clean-uninstall.html) at some point there were no Autodesk programs running or appearing in the installed apps list after a reboot. I ran some of the steps around a dozen times, with reboots in between also used the Microsoft ["Uninstall troubleshooter"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d) in particular.

From the Autodesk instructions:

```
Search "Uninstall Tool" on the Windows Start button.
Open it and select all the Autodesk software to remove them.
Note.  The Uninstall Tool is only available for Autodesk software that is not using the new Installation Experience. If the tool is not available on your system, skip to Step 3. 
Click Start > type appwiz.cpl > press ENTER. The Control Panel opens. Uninstall all Autodesk software.
Go to C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AdODIS\V1 and run RemoveODIS.exe to uninstall Autodesk Access. 
Go to C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared and run AdskLicensing\uninstall.exe to uninstall Autodesk Licensing Desktop Service. 
Run Microsoft Program Install and Uninstall Troubleshooter to check and remove any residual Autodesk software on the system. For Autodesk Genuine Service, please go to Step 11. 
Click Start > type %temp% > press ENTER. The Temp folder opens. Remove all folders and files, skip any in use.
Remove the three files starting with adsk in C:\ProgramData\FLEXnet (Note. One of the three files is hidden).
Remove the following folders:
C:\Program Files\Autodesk
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared
C:\Program Files (x86)Autodesk
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Autodesk Shared
C:\ProgramData\Autodesk (Note: This folder might be hidden)
%localappdata%\Autodesk (Note: This folder might be hidden)
%appdata%\Autodesk (Note: This folder might be hidden)
Open Windows Registry Editor (REGEDIT) and remove the following:
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Autodesk
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Autodesk
Click Start > type appwiz.cpl > press ENTER. The Control Panel opens. Uninstall Autodesk Genuine Service.
```

So just expect to spend several hours uninstalling, if at any point you don't want Autodesk on your computer anymore.